# How to keep checked values checked after submit on a form?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I'm really a beginner at coding and I am creating a web page using a mix of HTML, ASAP, and JavaScript. I created a form and that has checkboxes and radio buttons. It takes in the users input, goes through a loop and produces the output.

Everything works but I'm currently stuck on keeping the selected values after submission. I've looked it up and everything is in PHP but I don't think ASP actually supports PHP. It doesn't read it.

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes and **all input controls keeps their new values after post back** with out do anything.

But if on code behind you change the value and set some default or make a redirect, then you have that you say.

in asp.net we use the `IsPostBack` to know that we have post back and not set again the values on any input control